# I can't run my app on my raspberry pi web server

Tags: apache, tomcat

I run my app in apache tomcat localhost on windows laptop and on my raspberry pi without a problem, however when I put my app on my raspberry pi webserver my app shows the classes, html, jsp, etc.  as a list of folders.

Any help with be appreciated.

Comment: are there any hints in the log? how did you deploy it? what did you do differently? please [edit] your question and add more information

Comment: The java classes & jsp files need to be deployed in a servlet container like Tomcat. A http webserver alone is not enough - and you seeing those resources as a list of files and folders sugests you don't have a proper Tomcat configuration.